# how to echo directory name

Tags: php, dir

how to echo directory name with images gallery

this code showing random images and i want to echo directory name with images please help me to fix this issue.

**i want like this

example

```
______________
|     this    |
|     is      |
|    image    |
|             |
|_____________|
 Directory Name
```

**

```
<?php

$directory = "./*/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

$imgs = '';
// create array
foreach($images as $image){ $imgs[] = "$image"; }



//shuffle array
shuffle($imgs);

//select first 20 images in randomized array
$imgs = array_slice($imgs, 0, 20);

?>



 <table id="results">
            <tr>
            </tr>
<tr>

<?php $num_of_files = 0; $i=0; foreach ($imgs as $img):?>
<td><a href="<?php echo $img ?>" target="_blank"><img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="<?php echo $img ?>thumb.jpeg" width=165 height=135 /></td>
<?php if (++$num_of_files == 12)break; ?>
  <?php if(++$i%3==0): ?>
    </tr><tr>
  <?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>

</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just `echo $directory` below the `<img>` tag?

```
<tr>
   <?php foreach ($imgs as $img): ?>
   <td>
      <a href="<?php echo $img ?>" target="_blank">
         <img class="shadow1" name="field-name" src="<?php echo $img ?>thumb.jpeg" width=165 height=135 />
      </a>
      <p><?php echo basename($directory); ?></p>
   </td>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

Do you not have access to this parameter in your current scope? Another option is:

```
<p><?php echo basename(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)); ?></p>
```

Comment: this is not working dear its showing only one directory name

Comment: See my updated answer. Try using [`pathinfo`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php).

Comment: i change $directory = "./*/"; this line to $directory = "movie/*/"; now all images directroy showing like this movie/lifeofpie i want only lifeofpie

Comment: Have you tried using my suggested solution?

Comment: yes now directory name is showing but i want only directory name not complete path name

Comment: See updated answer. You need to use: `basename(pathinfo($img, PATHINFO_DIRNAME))`

Answer (score 0):

```
echo  basename(realpath('./'));
```

**realpath**:

> realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and return the canonicalized absolute pathname.

and

**basename**:

> Given a string containing the path to a file or directory, this function will return the trailing name component.

Refer [basename](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) and [realpath](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php) on Official site.