# Use regex or modify array values in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, file

I'm trying to learn how to modify my array values, I have the following code generating a list of file names:

```
foreach (glob("gallery/*/*.png") as $files) {
    echo "$files <br />";
}
```

This returns values that are formatted as: *gallery/folder/image.png*

How can I modify the results to return only the folder name?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/14911749/1415724

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function [`dirname`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php) takes a path and returns the directory part. So you can do this:

```
foreach (glob("gallery/*/*.png") as $file) {
    echo "$file is in ".dirname($file)."<br>";
}
```

Or you can get an array of all the paths at once with `array_map`:

```
$files = glob("gallery/*/*.png");
$paths = array_map('dirname', $files);
```

Comment: Got it, so it's returning gallery/dirname now, how do you trim off the 'gallery/' bit?

Comment: @inexion: Double check the input then -- I took the question at its word.

Comment: so I'm learning PHP now, what's the best way to modify these results to return only the dirname? It's returning 'gallery/dirname', I want to trim off the 'gallery/' bit

Comment: @inexion: `$fixed = substr($path, strlen('gallery/'));`, but this works unconditionally and does not check that `$path` actually does begin with "gallery/".

Comment: thanks will give this a shot, assuming that the results will always be the same, this is a sane choice - no?